# Use bash to remove symbols from text file

Tags: regex, bash, vim

I have a bunch of txt-files containing stuff like this:

```
text_i_need_to_remove{text_i_need_to_retain}
text_i need_to_remove{text_i_need_to_retain}
...
```

How do I remove text before curly braces (and curly braces themselves) and retain just only `text_i_need_to_retain`?

Comment: That's a very basic regular expression application; thousands of tutorials on the Internet will teach you this. In Vim: Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting everything upto `{` or `}` at end of line

```
:%s/.*{\|}$//g
```

From `bash` shell, you can use text processing tools like `sed` and `awk`. Assume file is named `ip.txt`

1) With `sed`, which is pretty similar to regex we used inside `vim`. The `-i` flag allows to make change in place, i.e it modifies the input file itself.

```
$ sed -i 's/.*{\|}$//g' ip.txt
```

2) With `awk`, one can again use substitution or in this case, split the line on curly brackets and use only the second column.

```
$ awk -F'{|}' '{print $2}' ip.txt > tmp && mv tmp ip.txt
```

If you have `GNU awk`, there is `-i inplace` option for in place editing

```
$ gawk -i inplace -F'{|}' '{print $2}' ip.txt
```

To make changed to all files in current directory, use

```
sed -i 's/.*{\|}$//g' *
```

Or if they have common extension, say `.txt`, use

```
sed -i 's/.*{\|}$//g' *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes sense now :)

Answer (score 3):

`:%s/^.*{\(.*\)}$/\1/` or in bash, `sed 's/^.*{\(.*\)}$/\1/ foo.txt`

`\(.*\)` is a control group which feeds into `\1` and looks like a lumbering zombie.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this in vim;

```
:%s/^.*{// | %s/}$//
```

you can also use this script; first run this, if everythink is ok, uncomment sed with -i option as below;

```
#!/bin/bash

for item in $(ls /dir/where/my/files/are)
do
sed -i 's/^.*{//;s/}$//' /dir/where/my/files/are/$item
done
```

sed -i ; inplace replace

or

Only use as below;

```
  sed -i 's/^.*{//;s/}$//' /dir/where/my/files/are/*
```

Comment: Thank you!
So, how would it look like in bash? 

    for item in $(ls /dir/where/my/files/are); 
        do vim $item :%s/^.*{// | s/.\{1}$// ; 
    done

Something like that?

Comment: Yesss, great, just what I needed. Thank you! :)

Comment: Mustafa, could you please tell if there is opportunity not to display every single line on terminal?

Comment: avoid [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)... and you could simply do `sed -i 's/^.*{//;s/}$//' /path/to/dir/*`

Answer (score 1):

Perl can be used to do the substitution on all files:

`perl -i -pe 's/.*{|}$//g' *.txt`